# Parallelise list of independent instructions with OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have a (long) list of independent instruction that can be executed in parallel. These are not in a loop, they are simply like this:

```
istr1;
istr2;
...
istrN;
```

How can I parallelise them using OpenMP? I know I could manually split them among some Pthreads, but I was wondering if there's something more straightforward, and that can automatically adjust the number of threads to the number of CPUs, just like OpenMP does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what OpenMP sections are for.

```c
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   istr1;
   #pragma omp section
   istr2;
   ...
   #pragma omp section
   istrN;
}
```

Another option would be to use explicit tasks:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      #pragma omp task
      istr1;
      #pragma omp task
      istr2;
      ...
      #pragma omp task
      istrN;
   }
}
```

The tasks are created inside a `single` construct to prevent their creation from happening in all threads (thus preventing each task from being created *num_threads* times). Using explicit tasks might result in better performance since most OpenMP runtimes utilise rather stupid logic when scheduling sections.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Unfortunately I'm actually getting worse performance, likely because the compiler can do better optimisations on the original code, and the instructions are not enough to actually exploit parallelism.

Comment: OpenMP introduces some overhead. If the code for each section/task takes very little time to complete, then the overhead could be so high as to negate the benefits of running things in parallel. Also it could be that you are experiencing something like false sharing.